# How does MSBuild check whether a target is up to date or not?

Tags: msbuild, build-process

MSBuild emits the following message for up to date targets:

```
Skipping target "MyTarget" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

How is the actual check performed?

Comment: Are you talking about Copy task and SkipUnchangedFiles parameter?

Comment: I am talking about Target, not a Copy task

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check flow of [Incremental Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx):

> A target element can have both an Inputs attribute, which indicates
>   what items the target > expects as input, and an Outputs attribute,
>   which indicates what items it produces as output
>   MSBuild attempts to find a 1-to-1 mapping
>   between the values of these attributes. If a 1-to-1 mapping exists,
>   MSBuild compares the time stamp of every input item to the time stamp
>   of its corresponding output item. Output files that have no 1-to-1
>   mapping are compared to all input files. An item is considered
>   up-to-date if its output file is the same age or newer than its input
>   file or files.
>
> If all output items are up-to-date, MSBuild skips the target. This
>   incremental build of the target can significantly improve the build
>   speed. If only some files are up-to-date, MSBuild executes the target
>   but skips the up-to-date items, and thereby brings all items
>   up-to-date. This is known as a partial incremental build.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that msbuild has some cache data with timestamps?

Comment: I believe whilst MSBuild doing such check it could persist some data structure which represents a list of files with timestamps, but not sure how long it keep this in memory because it makes sense only for particular In&&Out directories pair

Comment: @sergtk: It tracks all the files read & written to (as well as the relevant command lines) in tracking log files ("tlogs"). You can see these in the intermediate directory. The timestamps are not saved -- as quoted by sll, if an input is more up to date than an output then the output is recompiled, so all it needs to do this check is the dependency graph. (I personally would have preferred the timestamps be saved, because it would cut down on corner cases, but alas...)

Comment: Does anyone know what the tolerance is on the timestamp check? When I have several projects (with `ProjectReference`), it will rebuild the reference multiple times when they are done in quick succession. If I wait a minute between each project then they correctly see that the dependency it built earlier is up to date and skips it.

Answer (score 7):

MSBuild compares the input and output file timestamps to determine whether a file is up to date. See [Incremental Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx) for details.