# Publishing my asp.net mvc web application using Visual Studio Web Deploy will list some files as need to be deployed , although i did not modify them

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application , and i am using Visual Studio 2013 , to publish my web application to an online hosting using web deploy.

now i published my web application correctly. and i check it online and every thing is working well.. then today i modify a view named "Contact.cshtml" and a file named "style.css", and then I try to publish again. i was expecting that only the two files will be shown in the preview window since they differ from the publish files. but i was surprised that my `project.dll` is being listed although i did not chnage it (i did not modify any cs file) and the modified date for this .dll is that same modified date which is online..so can anyone adivce on this ?

here is how the preview window inside VS  2013 looks like:-

[image]

So can anyone advice why my project.dll file is listed although i did not modify it  since i did my last web deployment ?

Comment: Did you rebuild your solution / project before deploying? If so, your project may be getting assigned a new assembly version during the build, and that may be causing it to be included in the deploy.

Comment: @Chase no i did not rebuild... very confusing.. the last modified date for the.dll is the exact date when i did the first deployment. i build , deploy,,, then today i modify the two files..

Comment: Here's the MSDN [Web Deployment FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx) page that doesn't offer a lot of insight. But maybe you can check any options you might have set.

Comment: There's also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005034/3585500) that has some ideas.

Comment: I can confirm this oddity. I performed a web deploy to my server, and then without any changes performed a second web deploy immediately after, and indeed it thinks several of my files need updating. I did notice, however, that the "Date modified" reported in the Web Deploy window is not the same as the "Date modified" reported in Windows Explorer. They are different dates, which leads me to believe that Visual Studio may have some sort of internal file data information for files in a solution. Perhaps this is due in part to some sort of Visual Studio caching technique?

Comment: @Chase can you adivce what do you mean by "Date Modified" inside windows explorer ?

Comment: @johnG When browsing your file system in Windows Explorer, the window on the right will have various columns, typically "Name", "Type", "Size", and "Date Modified" (or possibly "Date Created") -- if you don't see "Date Modified", right-click any of the column headers and you should see a context menu with various options, one of which is "Date Modified". The date-time listed in the "Date Modified" column on my local file system is what I was using to compare with what Visual Studio was reporting as the "Date Modified" for files it was deploying, and that's where I noticed a discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Either you ran the project before publishing and/or your are building your views in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your `style.css` and `Contact.cshtml` files have the wrong Build Action. The proper build action for these files should be "Do not copy", which seems counter-intuitive since the Web Deploy will copy it anyway. You can change the Build Action by selecting each file in the solution explorer and setting the appropriate value.